# JSON.NET deserialize and Remove objects

Tags: json, vb.net

I currently have an integration with an outside party. They recently added some more criteria to the json string I am parsing. I am loading this string into a datatable so parts of the string has to be removed in order to load with no errors. Currently I just remove withdrawals and deposits from the string itself. I then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to load the String into a datatable.

Below is an example of what I currently do. I am also trying to remove the below "address" json. When adding .Replace(address, "") to my jsonstring variable it will not remove like deposits or withdrawals does.

Is this the correct method of doing this or is there a better way removing sections of JSON?

The json they added is:

```
"address": {
                "address1": "9261 Test St.",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "Irvine",
                "state": "CA",
                "zip": "92618"
            },


rmvResults = "{" & ControlChars.Quote & "results" & ControlChars.Quote & ":"
Dim deposits As String = "," & ControlChars.Quote & "deposits" & ControlChars.Quote & ":[]"
Dim withdrawals As String = "," & ControlChars.Quote & "withdrawals" & ControlChars.Quote & ":[]"
Dim address As String = "," & ControlChars.Quote & "address" & ControlChars.Quote & ":{}"
jsonstring = syncClient.DownloadString(url).Replace(ControlChars.Quote, """").Replace(rmvResults, "").Replace(deposits, "").Replace(withdrawals, "").Replace(address, "") 'Removes beginning class. 
jsonContent = jsonstring.Remove(jsonstring.Length - 1) 'removes last character (closing tag)
```

Current JSON Structure:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "tp_id": "",
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "company": "",
            "address": {
                "address1": "",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "zip": ""
            },
            "phones": {
                "home_phone": ,
                "work_phone": ,
                "cell_phone": ""
            },
            "custom_fields": {
                "Contact Type": "",
                "Vehicle Make": "",
                "Vehicle Model": "",
                "Vehicle Year": ""
            },
            "balance": ,
            "pending_balance": ,
            "fleet": "",
            "deposits": [
                {
                    "id": "",
                    "process_date": "2017-10-24",
                    "cleared_date": "2017-10-27",
                    "amount": "90.00",
                    "transID": "",
                    "memo": "",
                    "status": ""
                }
            ],
            "withdrawals": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why is this marked as C#?

Comment: Did you tried Newtonsoft.Json? Use this library to deserialize JSON for you, and remove the unwanted part. Link: [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)

Comment: That code seems to have nothing to do with the title.  Its not using JSON.NET and not deserializing anything. If you are consuming it, you can easily omit the parts you dont want

Comment: Plutonix, sorry still new to JSON. I added full json string

Comment: Currently i just remove withdrawals and deposits from the string itself. I then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to load the String into a datatable.

Comment: Can you share the deserialization code where you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`?  If you are deserializing to a fixed type then new, introduced JSON properties are generally ignored.  Also, can you share the JSON you receive initially before making any string-related modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the following code.

```
Public Shared Function Tabulate(json As String) As DataTable
    Dim jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(json)

    ' Find the first array using Linq
    Dim srcArray = jsonLinq.Descendants().Where(Function(d) TypeOf d Is JArray).First()
    Dim trgArray = New JArray()
    For Each row As JObject In srcArray.Children(Of JObject)()
        Dim cleanRow = New JObject()
        For Each column As JProperty In row.Properties()
            ' Only include JValue types
            If TypeOf column.Value Is JValue Then
                cleanRow.Add(column.Name, column.Value)
            End If
        Next

        trgArray.Add(cleanRow)
    Next

    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(trgArray.ToString())
End Function
```